# in an angular component, how to programmatically append a template to various locations

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my component A, i have a small reusable template #MyTpl that I would like to dynamically/programmatically add in various locations of the component A's template. `ngIf` could do the trick but I have a corner case with an ngSwitch:

```
<div class="compA" [ngSwitch]="mode">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="mode-1">
    <span>rofl</span>

  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="mode-2">
    <span>kikoo</span>
  </div>
  ...
  <div *ngSwitchCase="mode-n">
    <span>kikoo</span>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #MyTpl>
  <button (click)="onClickLol()">lol</button>
</ng-template>
```

Is there a way to append #MyTpl (conditionnaly) to the content of the currently cased `mode` ?

Comment: Is `#MyTpl` made only of HTML, or will there be Angular code ?

Comment: it does contain Angular code

Comment: Then you should make a new component, and use it with `<app-my-tpl>`. That's the Angular way of doing this.

Comment: Are you looking for this ? https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0):

Either switch to use standalone components or if you need to use template, you can do it with

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="MyTpl"></ng-container>
```

This places `MyTpl` template in place of `ng-container`

Comment: that's what I am doing now, but i was looking for a programmatic way of adding it